# Are you able to access the original system entity data?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm currently using the sys.date and sys.date-period entities

When using non-system entities you are able to access the original

DialogFlow Example:

[image: DialogFlow Example]

Is there any way to process the original when they are automatically remapped?

For instance, tomorrow is automatically remapped to "2018-04-06T12:00:00-06:00" or some date in the same format.

Am I able to retrieve the entry before the automated remapping? I.e access "tomorrow"

Comment: Please, don't add your example as a picture. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You can find the original value in the context object of the webhook request as seen below.

```
{
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "tomorrow",
    "parameters": {
      "date": "2018-08-15T12:00:00-07:00",
      ...
    },
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": ".../fdas",
        "lifespanCount": 5,
        "parameters": {
          "date": "2018-08-15T12:00:00-07:00",
          "date.original": "tomorrow",
          ...
        }
      },
      ...
    ],
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

For the example above you can access it through the `webhookRequest.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0].parameters['date.original']`

You can also access the original value within responses defined in Dialogflow's console with `#contextname.parametername.original`:
[image]

Comment: Sometimes `queryResult` does not contain `outputContexts`. When I tested my test utterance at GUI console, I could find the `outputContexts`. But my code calls web api directly, and there were no `outputContexts` in the result for system entities. Interestingly, no problems in custom entities. Do you know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Your original date would be under `period_org`. Just need to make sure the value is `$[your_period_value].original`. Just stumbled upon this :)

[image: Dialogflow entity]